# No class cast exception when I use generics

Tags: java, generics, casting

This program...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] table = (String[]) new Object[20];

    table[1] = "bla";

}
```

... generates a cast exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
at tests.App.main(App.java:10)
```

However, the same operation done using generics, do not generate any errors:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        

    doIt("bla");

}

public static <V>void doIt(V val) {

    V[] table = (V[]) new Object[20];

    table[1] = val;     
}
```

Why is it different using generics?

Comment: Maybe it is assigning type `Object`to `V`

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570877/java-covariant-array-bad

Answer (score 3):

It's because of [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). At runtime, `V[]` is just `Object[]`.