# Why in Covariant class in Scala var in constructor is forbidden?

Tags: scala, covariance, covariant-return-types

I have class

```
class GenericClass[+T] (var x: T) {}
```

When I try to compile it I get:

```
Error:(6, 33) covariant type T occurs in contravariant position in type T of value x_=
  class GenericCellImm[+T] (var x: T) {
```

How to fix it? What is the problem reason?

Comment: Quite probably [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) (BTW using var is anyway discouraged)

Comment: The compiler knows where a covariant type would not be type-safe and does not allow that. The passed parameter can be a `var` or the type can be covariant, but you can't have both.

Comment: The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570877/java-covariant-array-bad) demonstrates the dangers of mixing covariant types with mutable variables.

Answer (score 1):

Covariant generic type means that if you have classes `Base` and `Child` that extends `Base`, then in every context where `GenericClass[Base]` is a correct type using an object of type  `GenericClass[Child]` will also be correct. As a rough approximation it means that if your `GenericClass[T]` provides read-only API, you may make `+T` covariant because it is always safe to return `Child` instead of `Base`. However this is not true if you have some writeable API in your `GenericClass[T]`. Consider following code:

```
def writeDefault(gc: GenericClass[Base]):Unit = {
   gc.x = new Base()
}
```

This code is safe if `gc` is really of type `GenericClass[Base]` but if you let `GenericClass[Child]` there, you'll write a value of type `Base` to a field that is typed with `Child` and this breaks expected type safety. Consider

```
class Base(){}
class Child(childField:Int) extends Base {}

def bad():Unit = {
   val gc = new GenericClass[new Child(1)]
   writeDefault(gc)
   println(gc.childField) // Oops! there is no childField in Base
}
```

And this is exactly why the compiler doesn't allow your code with covariance.

If you want get some real suggestion on how to fix it, you should describe the higher-level problem you are trying to solve. Without such a description it is really hard to guess whether just using `val` instead of `var` is what you need or whether you just need to remove covariance altogether or if you need a more complicated code.